# Cancel drag disappearing cart in react dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am stuck with the react dnd library. When I cancel my task to move in another column. My cart disappeared.

Another issue is that when I try to sort card in the same columns then also card got disappeared.

Could you please help me to sort out that issue please?

I will be very thankful to you.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { PencilIcon, PlusIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe } from 'pubsub-js';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { ColorPickerModal, CreateTaskModal, CreateUpdateMilestoneModal, TooltipTrigger } from '../../../../components';
import { analyticsEvents, analyticsSources, defaults, events } from '../../../../constants';
import { notifyError } from '../../../../helpers';
import analytics from '../../../../utils/analytics';
import { useGetTasksByMilestoneId, useIntersectionObserver } from '../../../../hooks';
import { TaskCard } from '../../../../components/task-board/components';

const Skeleton = () => (
    <div className={'bg-gray-tertiary animate-pulse p-2 rounded-lg divide-y divide-gray-100 dark:divide-gray-900 space-y-2'}>
        {/* TOP */}
        <div className='space-y-1 animate-pulse'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between mb-2'>
                {/* GOAL NAME */}
                <div className='w-24 h-4 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
                <div className='w-4 h-4 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
            </div>
            <div className='w-11/12 h-2.5 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
            <div className='w-11/12 h-2.5 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full ml-auto'></div>
            <div className='w-11/12 h-2.5 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
        </div>
        {/* BOTTOM */}
        <div className='flex items-center pt-2 space-x-2 animate-pulse'>
            <div className='w-16 h-4 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
            <div className='w-4 h-4 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
            <div className='w-4 h-4 bg-gray-secondary rounded-full'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const MilestoneColumn = ({
    goalId,
    shouldShowGoalName,
    updateTaskAction,
    watchTaskAction,
    unwatchTaskAction,
    archiveTaskAction,
    unArchiveTaskAction,
    deleteTaskAction,
    readRoomAction,
    saveTaskAsTemplateAction,
    isIAmGoalMember,
    haveGoalEditAccess,
    haveCreateAccess,
    haveEditAccess,
    haveDeleteAccess,
    createTaskAction,
    createTaskFromTemplateAction,
    milestone,
    createMilestoneAction,
    updateMilestoneAction,
    refetchMilestone
}) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const loadMoreButtonRef = useRef(null);

    const [milestoneForm, _milestoneForm] = useState({
        isColorPickerVisible: false,
        showUpdateMilestoneModal: false,
        showCreateTaskModal: false,
        isUpdating: false
    });

    const {
        tasks,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        fetchNextPage,
        hasNextPage,
        isFetchingNextPage,
        refetch: refetchTasks,
        setTasks
    } = useGetTasksByMilestoneId(milestone.id);

    useIntersectionObserver({
        root: ref,
        target: loadMoreButtonRef,
        onIntersect: fetchNextPage,
        enabled: !!milestone.id && hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let taskAddInMilestoneUnSub = () => { };

        if (milestone.id) {
            taskAddInMilestoneUnSub = subscribe(events.TASK_ADDED_IN_MILESTONE_ + milestone.id, () => {
                refetchTasks();
            });
        }

        // unsubscribe all events
        return () => {
            unsubscribe(taskAddInMilestoneUnSub);
        };
    }, []);

    const dropHandler = (item) => {
        if (milestoneForm.isUpdating) return;

        _milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: true }));
        setTasks(old => ([...old, item]));

        updateTaskAction(item.id, { milestone_id: milestone.id }).then(() => {
            refetchTasks();
            _milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: false }));
        }).catch(() => {
            refetchTasks();
            notifyError(defaults.MESSAGES.ERROR, { id: defaults.MESSAGES.ERROR });
            _milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: false }));
        });
    };

    const dragEndHandler = ({ item, milestoneId }) => {
        setTasks(old => old.filter(task => task.id !== item.id));
    };

    // dnd functionality
    const [{ isOver, canDrop, handlerId }, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: 'task',
        drop: dropHandler,
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: monitor.isOver(),
            canDrop: monitor.canDrop() && isIAmGoalMember && haveEditAccess,
            handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId()
        })
    });
    const isActive = isOver && canDrop;
    drop(ref);

    const onSaveColumnColor = (hex) => {
        if (!haveGoalEditAccess) return;
        if (!isIAmGoalMember) {
            notifyError(defaults.MESSAGES.TASK_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED, { id: defaults.MESSAGES.TASK_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED });
            return;
        }

        const data = { background_color: hex.replace('#', '') };

        updateMilestoneAction(milestone.id, data).then(() => {
            refetchMilestone();
            _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, isColorPickerVisible: false }));
        });
    };

    const onEditColor = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (!haveGoalEditAccess) return;
        if (!isIAmGoalMember) {
            notifyError(defaults.MESSAGES.WORKFLOW_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED, { id: defaults.MESSAGES.WORKFLOW_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED });
            return;
        }

        _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, isColorPickerVisible: true }));
    };

    const onEditMilestone = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!haveGoalEditAccess) return;
        if (!isIAmGoalMember) {
            notifyError(defaults.MESSAGES.WORKFLOW_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED, { id: defaults.MESSAGES.WORKFLOW_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED });
            return;
        }

        _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, showUpdateMilestoneModal: true }));
    };

    return (
        <div
            className='flex flex-col w-[264px] 2xl:w-72 h-full overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden hidden-scrollbar border border-gray-secondary rounded-xl group/col'
        /* className={`min-w-[300px] px-2 mr-1 h-96 overflow-y-auto ${isActive ? 'bg-orange-100' : 'bg-orange-300'} border border-gray-900`} */
        >
            {/* COLUMN HEADER */}
            <div className='bg-gray-tertiary border-b border-gray-secondary w-full h-12 px-2 flex items-center space-x-2 rounded-t-xl sticky top-0 z-40 group'>
                <div className='flex-1 flex items-center space-x-2 truncate'>
                    {/* COLOR DOT */}
                    <div>
                        <div className='flex items-center justify-center w-3.5 h-3.5 rounded-full'>
                            <div
                                style={{ background: `#${milestone.background_color}` }}
                                className='w-3.5 h-3.5 rounded-full cursor-pointer'
                                onClick={onEditColor}
                            >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* TITLE & DATE */}
                    <div className='truncate'>
                        <div className='flex items-center space-x-2 truncate'>
                            <div className='flex items-center truncate'>
                                {/* HEADER TITLE */}
                                <TooltipTrigger trigger='hover' placement='bottom' tooltip={({ tooltipRef, getArrowProps, getTooltipProps }) => (<div {...getTooltipProps({ ref: tooltipRef, className: 'tooltip-container' })} > <div {...getArrowProps({ className: 'tooltip-arrow' })} />{milestone.title}</div>)}>
                                    {({ triggerRef }) => (
                                        <h2 ref={triggerRef} className='text-gray-primary text-base sm:text-base capitalize truncate'>
                                            {milestone.title}
                                        </h2>
                                    )}
                                </TooltipTrigger>
                                {/* EDIT ICON */}
                                {haveGoalEditAccess && isIAmGoalMember &&
                                    <TooltipTrigger trigger='hover' placement='bottom' tooltip={({ tooltipRef, getArrowProps, getTooltipProps }) => (<div {...getTooltipProps({ ref: tooltipRef, className: 'tooltip-container' })} > <div {...getArrowProps({ className: 'tooltip-arrow' })} />Edit milestone</div>)}>
                                        {({ triggerRef }) => (
                                            <span ref={triggerRef} onClick={onEditMilestone} className='opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 -ml-3.5 group-hover:ml-1 transition-all ease-in-out duration-200'>
                                                <PencilIcon className='h-3.5 w-auto text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-gray-300 cursor-pointer transition ease-in-out duration-200' />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                    </TooltipTrigger>
                                }
                            </div>
                            {/* NUMBER OF TASKS */}
                            {/* <TooltipTrigger trigger='hover' placement='bottom' tooltip={({ tooltipRef, getArrowProps, getTooltipProps }) => (<div {...getTooltipProps({ ref: tooltipRef, className: 'tooltip-container' })} > <div {...getArrowProps({ className: 'tooltip-arrow' })} />{tasksCount < 10 ? '0' : null}{tasksCount}</div>)}>
                                {({ triggerRef }) => (
                                    <div ref={triggerRef} className='flex items-center justify-center h-[18px] px-[5px] rounded bg-blue-100 dark:bg-gray-700 text-gray-primary text-xs leading-none'>
                                        {tasksCount > 99 ? '99+' : tasksCount}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </TooltipTrigger> */}
                        </div>
                        {/* start date & due date */}
                        {
                            milestone.start_date && milestone.due_date &&
                            <TooltipTrigger trigger='hover' placement='bottom' tooltip={({ tooltipRef, getArrowProps, getTooltipProps }) => (<div {...getTooltipProps({ ref: tooltipRef, className: 'tooltip-container' })} > <div {...getArrowProps({ className: 'tooltip-arrow' })} /><p>{DateTime.fromISO(milestone.start_date).toFormat('MMM dd, yyyy')}<span className='px-1.5'>-</span>{DateTime.fromISO(milestone.due_date).toFormat('MMM dd, yyyy')}</p></div>)}>
                                {({ triggerRef }) => (
                                    <p ref={triggerRef} className='text-gray-500 text-xs truncate'>
                                        {DateTime.fromISO(milestone.start_date).toFormat('MMM dd, yyyy')}
                                        <span className='px-1.5'>-</span>
                                        {DateTime.fromISO(milestone.due_date).toFormat('MMM dd, yyyy')}
                                    </p>
                                )}
                            </TooltipTrigger>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* ADD NEW TASK */}
            {
                haveCreateAccess &&
                <div
                    onClick={() => { analytics.track(analyticsEvents.CREATE_TASK_FORM_SUBMISSION_STARTED, { tmSource: analyticsSources.TASK_MILESTONE_VIEW }); _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, showCreateTaskModal: true })); }}
                    className={`${_.isEmpty(tasks) ? '' : '-mt-9 group-hover/col:mt-0'} h-max bg-slate-200 dark:bg-slate-700 w-full transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`}
                >
                    <div className='w-full flex items-center space-x-2 cursor-pointer group px-3 py-2'>
                        <PlusIcon className='w-5 h-auto text-gray-primary group-hover:bg-white dark:group-hover:bg-slate-800 p-1 rounded-full cursor-pointer transition ease-in-out duration-100' />
                        <div className='text-sm sm:text-base capitalize text-gray-primary !leading-none'>Add new task</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

            {/* COLUMN DRAG DROP AREA */}
            <div
                // className={`${isActive && 'bg-green-200 dark:bg-green-900/20 border-2 border-dashed border-green-500 rounded-b-xl !px-1.5 !pt-2'} ${!isOver && canDrop && 'bg-blue-200 dark:bg-blue-900/20 border-2 border-dashed border-blue-500 rounded-b-xl !px-1.5 !pt-2'} w-full flex-1 px-2 pt-2.5 space-y-2.5 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden transition-all ease-in-out duration-150`}
                className={`${isActive && 'bg-green-200 dark:bg-green-900/20 !border-green-500'} ${!isOver && canDrop && 'bg-blue-200 dark:bg-blue-900/20 !border-blue-500'} w-full flex-1 border-2 border-dashed border-transparent px-1.5 pt-2 space-y-2.5 rounded-b-xl overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden transition-all ease-in-out duration-150`}
                ref={ref}
                data-testid='column'
                data-handler-id={handlerId}
            >

                {/* {
                    isLoading &&
                    [...Array(3)].map((s, index) => (
                        <Skeleton key={index} />
                    ))
                } */}

                {/* TASK LIST */}
                {!isLoading && tasks && tasks.map((item, index) => (
                    <TaskCard
                        key={item.id}
                        item={item}
                        index={index}
                        shouldShowGoalName={shouldShowGoalName}
                        updateTaskAction={updateTaskAction}
                        watchTaskAction={watchTaskAction}
                        unwatchTaskAction={unwatchTaskAction}
                        archiveTaskAction={archiveTaskAction}
                        unArchiveTaskAction={unArchiveTaskAction}
                        deleteTaskAction={deleteTaskAction}
                        readRoomAction={readRoomAction}
                        saveTaskAsTemplateAction={saveTaskAsTemplateAction}
                        isIAmGoalMember={isIAmGoalMember}
                        haveEditAccess={haveEditAccess}
                        haveDeleteAccess={haveDeleteAccess}
                        onDragEnd={dragEndHandler}
                        milestoneId={milestone.id}
                    />
                ))}

                {
                    (isLoading || isFetching) &&
                    <Skeleton />
                }

                {/* load more button */}
                <div className='invisible flex-1 flex justify-center mx-auto p-2'>
                    <button
                        onClick={fetchNextPage} ref={loadMoreButtonRef}
                        className='bg-indigo-600 dark:bg-blue-600 md:hover:bg-indigo-700 dark:md:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 font-medium inline-flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-1.5 rounded-md text-xs sm:text-sm text-white w-max-content'>
                        Load more
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* COLUMN FOOTER */}
            {/* <div className='bg-gray-secondary w-full p-3 sticky bottom-0 z-30'>
                <div className='w-max flex items-center space-x-2 cursor-pointer group'>
                    <PlusIcon className='w-5 h-auto text-gray-primary group-hover:bg-white dark:group-hover:bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full cursor-pointer transition ease-in-out duration-100' />
                    <div className='capitalize text-gray-primary'>Add new task</div>
                </div>
            </div> */}
            {
                milestoneForm.isColorPickerVisible &&
                <ColorPickerModal
                    isOpen={milestoneForm.isColorPickerVisible}
                    hex={`#${milestone.background_color}`}
                    onSave={hex => onSaveColumnColor(hex)}
                    onClose={() => _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, isColorPickerVisible: false }))}
                />
            }

            {/* update milestone modal */}
            {
                milestoneForm.showUpdateMilestoneModal &&
                <CreateUpdateMilestoneModal
                    isOpen={milestoneForm.showUpdateMilestoneModal}
                    onClose={() => _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, showUpdateMilestoneModal: false }))}
                    milestone={{ ...milestone, ...(milestone.background_color && { background_color: `#${milestone.background_color}` }) }}
                    createMilestoneAction={createMilestoneAction}
                    updateMilestoneAction={updateMilestoneAction}
                    goalId={goalId}
                />
            }

            {/* create task modal */}
            {
                milestoneForm.showCreateTaskModal &&
                <CreateTaskModal
                    isOpen={milestoneForm.showCreateTaskModal}
                    onClose={() => {
                        analytics.track(analyticsEvents.CREATE_TASK_FORM_SUBMISSION_CANCELLED, { tmSource: analyticsSources.TASK_MILESTONE_VIEW });
                        _milestoneForm(old => ({ ...old, showCreateTaskModal: false }));
                    }}
                    createTaskAction={createTaskAction}
                    createTaskFromTemplateAction={createTaskFromTemplateAction}
                    goalId={goalId}
                    isGoalSelectionDisabled={!!goalId}
                    milestone={{ title: milestone.title, id: milestone.id }}
                />
            }
        </div >
    );
};

MilestoneColumn.propTypes = {
    goalId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    shouldShowGoalName: PropTypes.bool,
    isIAmGoalMember: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    haveGoalEditAccess: PropTypes.bool,
    haveCreateAccess: PropTypes.bool,
    haveEditAccess: PropTypes.bool,
    haveDeleteAccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    updateTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    watchTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    unwatchTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    archiveTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    unArchiveTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    readRoomAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    saveTaskAsTemplateAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    createTaskAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    createTaskFromTemplateAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    milestone: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    createMilestoneAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    updateMilestoneAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    refetchMilestone: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default React.memo(MilestoneColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
**Update the dropHandler and dragEndHandler function as follows:**

const dropHandler = (item) => {
if (milestoneForm.isUpdating) return;

_milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: true }));

updateTaskAction(item.id, { milestone_id: milestone.id })
.then(() => {
refetchTasks();
 _milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: false }));
    })
    .catch(() => {
      refetchTasks();
      notifyError(defaults.MESSAGES.ERROR, { id: defaults.MESSAGES.ERROR });
      _milestoneForm((old) => ({ ...old, isUpdating: false }));
 });
};

const dragEndHandler = ({ item, milestoneId }) => {
 setTasks((old) => [...old, item]);
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).